# how to stop user to use back button

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have one button on page, page name abc.aspx . when user click on that button
it should redirect to `finishwork.aspx` page.

After finishwork.aspx page user must not go back to `abc.aspx` page. when user press back button in browser, he should be redirect to `workallreadyfinish.aspx` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable caching on that pages and avoid caching the page.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: and with this code, we can use onbeforeunload page event to stop refreshing page or give warning

Answer (score 0):

`location.replace()` can be used to replace your page in the history.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this, but, as you are using ASP.NET and I'm going to assume, WebForms, why don't you make use of the `<asp:Wizard>` control?

You will be able to have a much detailed control over your steps and block the user to go back and all sort of nice things.

- If you want to take the normal way, you can always warn the user that the page will no longer be valid using a javascript event.
- You can also make use of hashing and submit the form by an ajax call instead of a normal POST
- You can write a cookie once the form is submitted and the next time, show such warning, so even if the user goes back and press the Submit button again, you will not care. Remember to erase the Cookie on `if (!Page.IsPostBack) {  ...  }`

Comment: Thanks for help, but any other way to do this using code other then Wizard control...?

Comment: I have told you 3 things if you don't want to use the control... did you read the entire answer?

Answer (score 0):

Having your user workflow around the browser back button is not such a good idea.
Browser back buttons are not entire in your control.

If you want to provide a logical back in your application, use a back button in your application.

If you only want that a user cannot go back to a page, you should [tell the browser not to cache it set the page to expire](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript function for this:-

```
function disableBackButton()
{
    window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
```