# How to disable Back button on Logout?

Tags: javascript

I am working on application with Iframes,on logging out of my application when i click
browser back button it loades application home page without asking for login.
so how can i load same page(login page) on back button.please help.

Thank You

Comment: Why not store login status in DB and check on page load.

Comment: On which technology you are wokring..?? `ASP.NET` or `Java`

Comment: Disabling back button for log out is a bad code.you have to use SESSION validation during login/log out

Comment: Disable caching on that pages and avoid caching the page. refer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12138488/1042848)

Comment: if you r using any server-side language than session maintain is the best way , are u using any server-side language??

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
window.history.forward();
```

Note that this does not really prevent the user from accessing that page, it will only make it more difficult. You should use session validation on the log out page for any form of security.